# async and await call an api for a response,

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have a function that looks like this,

```
const addItem = async(req, res, next) => {
    const itemApi = new Connector({
        url: '/item',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {},
        body: {item: "item name"}
    });
    try {
       const response = await itemApi.call();
       if(response.data && response.data.errors) {
           return response.data.errors;
       } else {
         return response.data;
       }
   } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
```

I invoking this method like this,

```
addItem(req, res, next)
   .then((response) => console.log(response))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

It seems that the `then` is always called and catch never called even if the api returns an error? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `addItem` catches the error.

Comment: `.catch()` will only be called if the function throws an error.

Comment: so if I didn't do try/catch it would work?

Comment: What kind of error are you referring to? It won't catch `response.data.errors`, since you're returning that normally. But if the API throws an exception, it should work.

Comment: The API is returning a 422 response code and errors objects

Comment: @Udders Yes, don't use `try`/`catch` inside the function if you actually want to handle the errors outside in a `.catch()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `try/catch bloc`k but not throwing back the error from catch block and hence the `.catch` of the function call is not executed since no unhandled error is present in the async function

You can throw and error and it would work as you expect it to

```
const addItem = async(req, res, next) => {
    const itemApi = new Connector({
        url: '/item',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {},
        body: {item: "item name"}
    });
    try {
       const response = await itemApi.call();
       if(response.data && response.data.errors) {
           return response.data.errors;
       } else {
         return response.data;
       }
   } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error(error);
   }
```